# Avoid conflict with other stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I have a site that uses some `css` that I can't modify. Then I have other `css` file that I just want to apply to a specific div.

This stylesheet looks like this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* third-party plugins */
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
@import "dev-plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css";
@import "dev-plugins/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.css";
@import "dev-plugins/codemirror/codemirror.css";
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
```

All the site works fine with the original css but If I add this stylesheet then everything breaks. Is there a way I can tag my css stylesheet so it will be applied to my div and its contents?

My div that I just want to affect with this css is:

```
<!-- page content container -->
<div class="container">
```

I just tried `<style type="text/css" scoped="true">` but I don't like that approach, I would like to know if I have to add `div.container` to every item in the css.

Any clue?

Comment: have you tried just adding an id attribute to your divs that you want to add your own css to?

Comment: @scoots I think you mean `class` because `id` is supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It only takes a second if you use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide)!

`/* third-party plugins */
    /*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
    @import url(dev-plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css);
    @import url(dev-plugins/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.css);
    @import url(dev-plugins/codemirror/codemirror.css);
    div.container {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    div.container article,
    div.container aside,
    div.container details,
    div.container figcaption,
    div.container figure,
    div.container footer,
    div.container header,
    div.container hgroup,
    div.container main,
    div.container menu,
    div.container nav,
    div.container section,
    div.container summary {
      display: block;
    }
    div.container audio,
    div.container canvas,
    div.container progress,
    div.container video {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    div.container audio:not([controls]) {
      display: none;
      height: 0;
    }
    div.container [hidden],
    div.container template {
      display: none;
    }
    div.container a {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    div.container a:active,
    div.container a:hover {
      outline: 0;
    }
    div.container abbr[title] {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    }
    div.container b,
    div.container strong {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    div.container dfn {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    div.container h1 {
      font-size: 2em;
      margin: 0.67em 0;
    }
    div.container mark {
      background: #ff0;
      color: #000;
    }`

Comment: Sass/Scss is a CSS pre-processor. I wrapped your stylesheet in an outer block (i.e., `div.container { [your styles] }`), and Sass compiled it into valid CSS, automatically pre-pending `div.container` to all your style rules. You can learn about Sass [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide), and try it out [here](http://www.sassmeister.com/). As Akinjide said, the LESS pre-processor would also work for this purpose.

Comment: Really?? Thats amazing. Will read more about it... so you dont have to add div.container manually, you just wrap all the styles withint the div.container { } and sass will do it for me?

Comment: You got it! Sass/Scss lets you nest style rules.

Comment: Do you know if there is any online service that do that without installing sass locally?

Comment: I included a link just like that in my first comment, which I found at the top of a Google search. Lots of sandboxes like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [codepen](http://codepen.io/) offer this feature, but you should install it locally if you intend to make it a part of your ordinary pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

adding "div.container" to every item in the CSS will allow you target every children element for "div.container", like so;

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="hlogo">
       <a href="/">My logo</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```
div.container {
  // styles code
}

div.container #header {
  // styles code
}

div.container #hlogo a {
  // styles code
}
```

You can use preprocessors like LESS, SCSS or any other to avoid DRY.